# The PATH variable is set to empty, how to fix it

Tags: linux, centos, bash, path-variables

I was trying to **set up a new environmental path** in my server, but **instead of using bash.basrc I used /etc/profile**. After editing I tried to **recompile the file using source** profile and it gave an error **not a valid identifier**. Now When I run **echo $PATH it shows nothing**, none of my programs are running,and I cant even edit the file to check if there was any error any help would be appreciated. I am using cent-os

Comment: Please add some snippets of the scripts/codes you modify and add labels to it.

Comment: For one thing you don't "compile" shell scripts. It sounds like you introduced a syntax error, but since you're not showing us any code it's hard to tell.

Comment: To start use: `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin` on command line.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can not use vim but you can use it like this:

```
/usr/bin/vim /etc/profile
```

rewrite your file and full fill your path.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've just got into the same situation. turned out i used '*set PATH <>*' by mistake in one of my scripts (instead of *setenv*).
i just '*unset PATH*' and then i was able to see **PATH** again. 
hope that would help someone